# Type narrowing & never functions

Tags: typescript, typechecking, narrowing

When using type narrowing with TypeScript, `never` functions do not react the same way every time.

```
const getValue = () => {
  const value = process.env.VARIABLE
  if (!value) process.exit(1)
  return value
}
```

In the example below, `getValue` inferred type is `() => string`, because `value` is typed `string | undefined`, and TypeScript is able to identify that the remaining code after `process.exit` is unreachable, and the return value is always a string.

```
const exit = () => {
  return process.exit(1)
}

const getValue = () => {
  const value = process.env.VARIABLE
  if (!value) exit()
  return value
}
```

In this second example, `exit` is typed `() => never`, and `getValue` inferred type is `() => string | undefined`, because TypeScript is unable to detect that the rest of the function is unreachable if `value` does not exists. However, if I add a `return` before the `exit` call (so `return exit()`), it works as desired.

Why does it works like this? Is there a way to make it work in the second case?

Comment: Assertions in control flow analysis, as implemented in [ms/TS#32695](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32695) only work for explicitly annotated functions (otherwise type checking becomes intractable, read that PR for more info). Therefore to make it work you have to annotate `exit()` yourself, as shown [in his playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WvzrRW). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz, it's exactly the answer I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TypeScript's support for functions that return `never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#better-support-for-never-returning-functions), as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#32695](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32695), only works if the function type is *explicitly [annotated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables)* to return `never`.  It would be nice if the type checker could just infer that, but allowing that would make [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) much harder to implement so that it performs well. As it says in the above-liked PR, "this particular rule exists so that control flow analysis of potential assertion calls doesn't circularly trigger further analysis".

So, to get the behavior you're looking for, you should annotate `exit` as being of type `() => never`, like this:

```
const exit: () => never = () => {
  return process.exit(1)
}
```

and then it just works:

```
const getValue = () => {
  const value = process.env.VARIABLE
  if (!value) exit()
  return value
}
// const getValue: () => string
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBGKEDGBTAzuuAzJI4DkAdhACaoBciKG6BA3AFCPIRHrwDmqMAagIYAbAK6o4AXjgAKAJQSAfHADejOHFbt4ANyGiJCJGkwA6VES3HeAQQBKASSsAhADIBRVXGDZpAQh0jUOWojdFMAD2AYKQBGGQ8oHmEoIjh-UUYAX2YNDjhUCJgKaTlxRSJULVQofVkFZXjE5IMaE3zImLisljZc7j5dVAAmGpLFFTUc7QH9YNpTc0tbBxd3NS9fNMC8gtkGmCSUzczGAHoT9R6uHgEAwaLa0rgOKGAiTiA)