# Returning `never` for function that always throws only narrows when not an object property

Tags: typescript

Let's say you have a function that throws a specifically configured error:

```
function throwMyError(): never {
    throw new Error("My Custom error")
}
```

And you have a nullable value:

```
declare const str: string | null
```

You could narrow that value to something non nullable like this:

```
if(!str) throwMyError()
str.toLocaleLowerCase() // fine
```

Now put that function call in an object literal, and it can no longer do the same narrowing:

```
const foo = { throwMyError }
if (!str) foo.throwMyError()
str.toLocaleLowerCase() // 'obj' is possibly 'null'.(18047)
```

Or:

```
const bar = {
    throwMyError: (): never => {
        throw new Error()
    }
}
if (!str) bar.throwMyError()
str.toLocaleLowerCase() // 'obj' is possibly 'null'.(18047)
```

Why does the narrowing not work when the throwing function is called from an object type?

Can this be addressed without creating a type predicate function?

[See Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=0#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFAFgJzgdwLIE8CiaGaAFAJQBciYApgG41qIDeAUIh8ultTZooWIkARHkQBhEAGcocALaJGxYWVYBfVqwAmNCABsAhmhqIICGYhloqVmGADmiAD7UQevZrNgLwOHEQAvCxcGDgERHBMGjDAiCQAhFZkiL5wAHSooXiCkeSsVhlwADJwEAZ6NCWYjOIGUjTkiAD0TYgA5HAARgBWbYgwUogADnBSUjCderjtYG56bWkkAIwAHAAMACwA7Kqe5lCInUaBLOycmVjZEdZxlLwMTAEAfKecbyE8tPw5pKpvGtFYgkkocjBluGEfnkCrISmUKlUanUGskWu0ur1+oMRmMJlMZnMFst1ttdqwYsCoGhkhdIddoVTCnDypUsEj6o00cA7DRNJogA)

---

Related question: [Type narrowing & never functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77802324/type-narrowing-never-functions)

But this doesn't seem to address this question because in all cases the function type *is* explicitly annotated to return `never`

Comment: The whole thing has to be annotated, but the type of `foo` and `bar` is inferred, not annotated. You need something like `const bar: {throwMyError(): never} = ...` instead.  Yes, this makes it much more difficult to do with anything but function declarations.  Does that answer it for you?  If so I'll write up the answer when I get home. If not, uh, what's the issue?

Comment: Ohhhhhh! My actual use case is actually adding properties to a function. like `myFn.functionThatThrows = (): never => { ... }`. So I guess I'd have to create an interface for that whole function and all it's properties, which is currently all just inferred for ease of use. Annoying, but doable. I'll gladly accept one of your excellent answers. Thanks @jcalz!

Comment: No problem. It will probably be a few more hours before I can get to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditions in which [a `never`-returning function is treated as an assertion that affects control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#better-support-for-never-returning-functions) are spelled out in the implementing PR, [microsoft/TypeScript#32695](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32695).  It looks like this:

> A function call is analyzed as an assertion call or never-returning call when
>
> - the call occurs as a top-level expression statement, and
> - the call specifies a single identifier or a dotted sequence of identifiers for the function name, and
> - each identifier in the function name references an entity with an explicit type, and
> - the function name resolves to a function type with an `asserts` return type or an explicit `never` return type annotation.
>
> An entity is considered to have an explicit type when it is declared as a function, method, class or namespace, or as a variable, parameter or property with an explicit type annotation. (This particular rule exists so that control flow analysis of potential assertion calls doesn't circularly trigger further analysis.)

The problem you're having with both `foo` and `bar` is that they are variables without an explicit [type annotation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables).  You've allowed the compiler to infer their types, which is in almost all other situations a perfectly fine and reasonable thing to do.  But apparently it's too hard to support that for assertion functions and `never`-returning functions; it is said to lead to type checker slowdowns and circularity warnings.

---

If you want `foo` and `bar` to work, then you will need to explicitly annotate them, like so:

```
declare const str: string | null;
const foo: { throwMyError(): never } = { throwMyError };
if (!str) foo.throwMyError();
str.toLocaleLowerCase(); // okay
```

or

```
declare const str: string | null; 
const bar: { throwMyError(): never } = {
    throwMyError: (): never => { throw new Error() }
};
if (!str) bar.throwMyError();
str.toLocaleLowerCase(); // okay
```

That's the behavior you wanted, and for the example code here it's not too much extra work.  But in practice this restriction on type annotations makes using `never`-returning and [assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) methods is a significant burden, as you find yourself needing to come up with explicit names for types that would otherwise be conveniently anonymous and inferred for you. Depending on the use case this can range from a minor annoyance (`const foo: Foo = ⋯`) to a complete dealbreaker (`const baz: Baz<Map<string, boolean>, "qux", [number, "hello"], Baz<Map<string, Date>, "quux", [boolean, "goodbye"], ⋯>> = ⋯`).  So proceed with caution.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=0#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFAFgJzgdwLIE8CiaGaAFAJQBciYApgG41qIDeAUIh8ultTZooWIkARHkQBhEAGcocALaJGxYWQDcrAL6tWbToggIZiGWiomYYAOaIAPtRAAbB4gC8ibAENUAOjQewACby5IgAPIgADN4ArIgA-IjCHgBGEMKIVGCODursnAZgRsBwcFTMXBg4BERwpJS8DEwariwVWHiCtYga6nowwIgkAIQmZIjFcN6olR01db2cJlNwADJwEB4ONGuYjOIeUjTkqogA9KeIcADWHria2mx5HAVGJmZQaBbWdllOLZ4+PyBYJjcJRWIJJKpdKZbILZ6GKCIZIeUytabtapCeq0RrdFq6PScDFVTpo8iZeiMVwAPnR3H4tH4ZJCWj0PSeiH6gxGHzGKLQUwZs2x8OMH2Waw2Wx2ewORzUZwu11u9x0nJeSLe4s+Vls9j+bgBKF8-iCchCYJi8USKTSGQNOU53OGozapLmx05S1kUs22ywcsOxyV4wsNDV2iAA)

Comment: Makes sense, but it's still a limitation that kind of sucks. I ended up *not* doing this and just importing a standalone function for this purpose instead. The real world case hit a very verbose about amount of deal breaking ugliness involving many generic function signatures that I was duplicating. But it's still nice to learn about this pitfall. Thank you.